# UIManagedDocument fileModificationDate doesn't change

Tags: objective-c, uimanageddocument, uidocument

Opening, closing, changing data and saving the document using the proper `UIDocument` Saving API methods will not change the value returned from the `fileModificationDate` property.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html):

> The modification date is updated by the `openWithCompletionHandler:`, `saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:`, and `revertToContentsOfURL:completionHandler:` methods.

But `fileModificationDate` always reports the creation date of the document file wrapper, regardless of the core data store being updated.

Certainly this is not normal behavior, right?

There is no specific extra code.  Simply this is a subclass of UIManagedDocument.  UIManagedDocument automatically manages a Core Data store inside the document wrapper.  Code as simple as this:

```
[document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Doc(Modified Date):  %@", document.fileModificationDate);
    }
}];
```

will always return the date the document was created.  Both the created and modified dates are the same, the date when the document was first saved for creation.  However, the modified date of the content store file changes, the creation date is the same as the document wrapper.

Comment: Can you add some example code?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. To troubleshoot further, you could try overriding `-fileAttributesToWriteToURL:forSaveOperation:error:` and logging `super`'s result before returning it. I think that's the method that should be responsible for generating the attributes. It looks like `-writeContents:andAttributes:safelyToURL:forSaveOperation:error:` should invoke that method. You could try working around it by overriding the first method.